# Final voltage at a node - calculation

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog

Considering the following circuit:
[image]

What would be the final voltage on Csn when its initial value is:

1. 0+x (degraded 0)
2. 1-x (degraded 1)

I tried calculating this, and:

1. I got a value of 0+x+2Vt between the two left-hand PMOS devices, and now what? How do I calculate the value below the lower PMOS?

[image]

2. I got a value of 0+Vt between the two left-hand PMOS devices

[image]

Comment: Show us your work. This is not a homework solution service.

Comment: Here, I added it. BTW I'm not looking for a "solution service". I'm trying to understand and I need help. That's all.